# Shared queue with coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a program where several coroutines are running in parallel to each other. They each result in `SUCCESFUL/DEFERRED`.

- When a task is `DEFERRED`, it should be added to a shared queue.
- When a task is `SUCCESFUL`, the queue should be drained (retry + clear)

Since this happens in parallel, I need to make sure that:

1. When draining the queue, the current tasks in it should only be retried & cleared once (if they fail again, they will effectively be added to the queue again).
2. Draining the queue can happen simultaneously for new tasks, e.g. if a drain is in progress, another one can start with new tasks since the last drain.

I thought a `Mutex` would be a great fit for this, but it turns out that I just end up creating a deadlock due to multiple coroutines trying to drain the queue simultaneously.

I suspect a channel/actor might suffice to make this work, but Im having a hard time grasping how I can defer tasks for execution at a later point in time with it.

How can I make this work?

Comment: I'm confused with the description. What do you mean by "drain"? Remove a successful task from the queue? Why the task that is currently executing is still in the queue? For retrying? Also, do you have a single queue or multiple queues? Because for me the list of tasks that wait to be executed, tasks that are being executed and list of deferred tasks seem like 3 different things, but you didn't explain this part. Also, the description sounds like you want to retry successful tasks which is pretty strange.

Comment: @broot Drain -> Empty the queue and retry each task that was in it at the time. Single queue.

Comment: Ahh, I think I get it. So it's a queue of tasks that couldn't execute, so they asked to be retried in the future, when other dependent tasks finish, correct? Could you provide the code of your solution using Mutex? I think it should work properly - as long as you don't do too much in the critical section: only add items and then launch tasks asynchronously.

Comment: Also, if I'm correct that this is some kind of tasks dependency mechanism where tasks consume data produced by other tasks (or just wait for some flag to be set) then I would be concerned with this scenario: 1. Task A checks an output of task B. 2. Task B produces its output and finishes with `SUCCESSFUL`. 3. Task A finishes with `DEFERRED`. We end up with a deadlock.

Comment: @broot You are correct! The issue I believe Im seeing when using Mutex is that Task A finishes succesfully, resulting in draining the queue with Task B; when B is executed succesfully as well - theres an "inner" drain, which then causes the deadlock to happen.  Ive put together some code using actor, but I believe the same thing can be acheived using a regular channel; but I still need to run some more tests before I can 100% verify that it works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Ive worked this out using a simple channel. Numerous clients issue operations (flush/retry) and theyre processed sequentially in the launch block. This passes my tests, hopefully it can help someone else out there. If I got something wrong, feel free to correct me in the comments!

```
sealed interface Operation {

    object Flush : Operation
}

fun interface Retry : Operation {

    suspend operator fun invoke()
}

private val channel = Channel<Operation>(UNLIMITED)

init {
    scope.launch {
        val pending = mutableListOf<Retry>()

        for (operation in channel) {
            when (operation) {
                is Retry -> {
                    pending += operation
                }
                is Flush -> {
                    if (pending.isNotEmpty()) {
                        pending.forEach { retry ->
                            retry()
                        }
                        pending.clear()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```